# Rewrite page on subdomain to another

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have wordpress multisite
I have a link on a subdomain like below

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/parameter-fruits
```

I want to have RewriteRule and read the parameter, I have used below to my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)-fruits$  http://subdomain.domain.com/test/?fruit=$1
```

It works, but the problem is the URL appears

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/test/fruit=parameter
```

instead of

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/parameter-fruits
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this

for wordpress you can use your theme `function.php` and add the rewrite rule as below

```
if (strpos($actual_link, "subdomain.domain.com") !== false)

{
    add_rewrite_rule('(^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)-fruits$','index.php?pagename=test','top');
    function add_query_vars( $query_vars )
    {
        $query_vars[] = 'pid';
        return $query_vars;
    }
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars' );
}
```

once you upload the file just flush rewrite, easiest way is to go the settings->>permalinks and press save

at your php file you can use something like below

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Explode and get the required parameters